# Given $\tan\beta=\frac{n\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{1-n\sin^2\alpha}$, show that $\tan(\alpha-\beta)=(1-n)\tan\alpha$

Tags: trigonometry

Given $$\tan\beta=\frac{n\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{1-n\sin^2\alpha},$$ show that $\tan(\alpha-\beta)=(1-n)\tan\alpha$.

Now I used formula for $\tan(A-B)$ and then put value of $\tan\beta$ and so I am able to prove the answer, but I asked this question because I wanted to know if there are other ways to do it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With
$$\tan\beta=\frac{n\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{1-n\sin^2\alpha}$$
we write
$$n=\frac{\tan\beta}{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha+\tan\beta\sin^2\alpha}$$
so
\begin{eqnarray}
\color{blue}{1-n}&=&
\frac{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha+\tan\beta\sin^2\alpha-\tan\beta}{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha+\tan\beta\sin^2\alpha}\\
&=&
\frac{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha-\cos^2\alpha\tan\beta}{\sin\alpha\cos\alpha+\tan\beta\sin^2\alpha}\\
&=&
\frac{\tan\alpha-\tan\beta}{\tan\alpha+\tan\beta\tan^2\alpha}\\
&=&
\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\tan\alpha}\tan(\alpha-\beta)}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

As we need to eliminate $\beta,$  write $\tan\beta=\tan\{\alpha-(\alpha-\beta)\}$ and expand.

For the RHS, $$\frac{n\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{1-n\sin^2\alpha}=\dfrac{\dfrac{n\sin\alpha\cos\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha}}{\dfrac{1-n\sin^2\alpha}{\cos^2\alpha}}=\dfrac{n\tan^2\alpha}{1+(1-n)\tan^2\alpha}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint...you can rewrite $\tan\beta$ as $$\frac{n}{1+(1-n)\tan\alpha}$$ then use the compound angle formula for $\tan(\alpha-\beta)$

Comment: isnt it the same as i did

Comment: You didn't actually show us what you did